# How to keep or remove grey margin for geom_tile on all facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

You can see on one group there is horizontal grey margin, on the other there is none.

How can I make the margin consistent across the facets?[image]

```
expand.grid(x=1:3, y=1:3)
a<-expand.grid(x=1:3, y=1:3)
a$value=rnorm(9)
a$group=1
b<-expand.grid(x=3, y=1:3)
b$value=rnorm(3)
b$group=2
c<-rbind(a,b)
ggplot(c, aes(x=factor(x), y=factor(y), fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() + facet_grid(.~group, scale="free_x", space="free_x")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `expand=c(0,0)` inside the `scale_x_discrete()` and `scale_y_discrete()` to remove grey area.

```
  +scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))
```

Comment: So it is not possible to set each facet with same amount of horizontal margin given that the facet widths are different? I guess the value in expand is the portion.

Comment: expand argument consists of two numbers - first for multiplication, second for additive expansion. As in second facet you have only one x values then it seems that expand= doesn't give the same output. If there are more than 1 x values then you can use scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,1))